# Is it possible to link to a unique class [HTML]?

Tags: html

Say in an HTML sheet I have

```
<div class="potato" id="mushrooms">
    <!-- stuff -->
</div>
```

Assuming this is the only instance of class potato, would it be possible to link to this div with an `<a>` tag using class potato instead of its ID (through `<a href="#mushrooms">`)?

Comment: Check this so thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567836/anchor-tag-to-go-to-the-beginning-of-a-div-class-w-using-jquery

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567836/anchor-tag-to-go-to-the-beginning-of-a-div-class-w-using-jquery

Comment: Default behavior for anchors relies on ID. If you want to use class, you'll have to use a javascript workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With native HTML, no. If you want to do that, you have to override the browsers default behavior in JavaScript.